# Complexity of a linked list which eliminates redundant elements

Tags: c, linked-list, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I want to calculate the complexity of this function. The following code eliminates redundant elements from an ordered list.

My answer to its complexity is `O(n²) = O(n*n)` "n" for the first `while` and "n" for the second `while`.

Is my answer correct? If not, how to correctly calculate the complexity?

```
liste redondance(liste l){
liste red,p,prev;
if(l==NULL)
   return l;
red=l;
while(red!=NULL){
   p=red->suivant;
   prev=red;
   while(p!=NULL){
       if(p->val==red->val){
           prev->suivant=p->suivant;
           free(p);
           p=prev->suivant;
       }
       else{
           p=p->suivant;
           prev=prev->suivant;
       }
   }
   red=red->suivant;
   }
  return(l);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So,the list is unsorted?

Comment: @wildplasser thank you for your answer. The list is already sorted

Comment: In that case the duplicate(s) can only be directly suivant. (and you would n't need an O(n*n) algoritm)

Comment: @wildplasser i don't understand your answer. you mean, i don't need the while loop?

Comment: If the list is sorted, the algorithm becomes linear.  "Is previous value same as current, then remove current"  One walk through list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is right.

The outer loop goes through all the elements, and the inner loop goes through all the elements *after* the one the outer loop is on.

On average the inner loop goes through half the elements, but that makes no difference to the complexity, which is still O(n²).

Answer (score -1):

```
void undup(struct llist* ll)
{
for( ;ll; ll=ll->next) {        //walk the chain
        struct llist **pp,*del;
        for(pp = &ll->next; del = *pp;) {
                // since the list is sorted, duplicates MUST be adjecent.
                // if the next node has a different value, there are no more dups
                // (wrt ll->val) in the rest of the chain
                if (del->val != ll->val) break;
                *pp = del->next;
                free(del);
                }
        }
return;
}
```

---

Complexity is O(n), obviously. (the inner loop shortens the chain, or executes only once)

Comment: "del" is not initialized? and why did you use declare ll as pointer in the function parameter?same i don't understant this notation "llist**pp"

Comment: I don't typedef pointers (since it is a bad habit) and `; del = *pp;` is an assignment.

Comment: and for the complexity?

Comment: Complexity is O(n), obviously. (the inner loop shortens the chain, or executes only once)